# Microdata Rich snippets review & photo

Tags: search, photo, microdata

Is there any possibility to show a photo of a reviewed Person in the google search result of a review aggregate just like in a recipe?

http://www.google.com/help/hc/images/webmasters_173379_en.png

I have a `div` with `itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Review-aggregate"` and all relevant data marked up inside including an `img` with a profile-photo marked like this:

```
<img itemprop="photo" ...
```

In google developer´s rich snippet testing tool I see all that information including the photo and its path, but the preview search result only contains the rating stars and stuff like recent review text, pubDate and author, while in the specs on schema.org it doesn't look like there's another solution.

Is there any solution? Thanks and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Please read carefully this manual:
   https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/146645

You can find there that photo property is for the item being reviewed, not for reviewer.

2. Aggregate review is for average rating. Reviewed person is actual for individual reviews.